# How to create multiple AutoFilter at different rows using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I want to create AutoFilters at multiple places in an excel sheet using Apache POI. (e.g. at row 2 & at row 8).

```
hssfSheet.setAutoFilter(new CellRangeAddress(2, 4, 6, 3)); 
hssfSheet.setAutoFilter(new CellRangeAddress(8, 5, 3, 5));
```

I've been adding it like mentioned above but second filter is overriding the first one and when excel sheet is created I can see only one. 
Can someone please help me.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: an Excel worksheet can only have 1 filter range per sheet. that filter range can filter on multiple items though.

Comment: but from GUI of microsoft excel I can create filter at multiple rows. Is this like apache POI is allowing to create only one filter per sheet?

Comment: are you trying to filter a dataset with multiple conditions? or place multiple filters on different datasets within a sheet?

Comment: I want to add basic filter. without any condition. Please find snapshot attached here http://i.stack.imgur.com/pctKK.png

Comment: I want to place multiple filters on different datasets within a sheet.

Comment: your image shows `Data Tables` not stand-alone `AutoFilters`. It's not possible to set multiple `AutoFilters` on a sheet. However, a sheet can have as many `Data Tables` as you want, which automatically show the filter drop-down arrows. You can turn an existing dataset into a `Table` that will automatically show the filters.

Comment: Thanks @ScottHoltzman . I was confused between AutoFilter & DataTables.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman : Do u have any sample example to insert DataTable inside HSSFSheet ?

Comment: As far as I know, It's no option to use tables in HSSFSheet. You should change sheet type to XSSFSheet

Comment: @DaniilLopatin : I want to download this worksheet in xls format. & because of that I have to use HSSFSheet only.

Answer (score 1):

Use should use `XSSFSheet` and create `CTTable`. Sheet may contain many tables.

Here is code for adding table to sheet. Please ensure that cells were created and exist.

```
private void createExcelTable(XSSFSheet sheet, AreaReference reference, int tableId, 
String name) {
    XSSFTable table = sheet.createTable();
    table.setDisplayName(name);
    CTTable cttable = table.getCTTable();

    // Style configurations
    // CTTableStyleInfo is available in ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar.
    // Replace with it your poi-ooxml.
    CTTableStyleInfo style = cttable.addNewTableStyleInfo();
    style.setName("TableStyleLight1");
    style.setShowColumnStripes(false);
    style.setShowRowStripes(true);

    // Set which area the table should be placed in
    cttable.setRef(reference.formatAsString());
    // id starts from 1
    cttable.setId(tableId);
    cttable.setName(name);
    cttable.setDisplayName(name);

    // first row is used for header with filter
    CTAutoFilter autoFilter = cttable.addNewAutoFilter();
    autoFilter.setRef(reference.formatAsString());

    CTTableColumns columns = cttable.addNewTableColumns();
    // sets count of columns for current table
    short firstColumn = reference.getFirstCell().getCol();
    short lastColumn = reference.getLastCell().getCol();
    columns.setCount(lastColumn - firstColumn + 1);

    for (int i = firstColumn; i <= lastColumn; i++) {
        // create columns
        CTTableColumn column = columns.addNewTableColumn();
        column.setName("Column" + i);
        // id starts from 1
        column.setId(i + 1);
    }
}
```

Example of AreaReference:

```
new AreaReference(new CellReference(0, 0), new CellReference(4, 5));
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniil. It worked. But how can i use this in HSSFSheet?

Comment: @TruptiKanase: I didn't worked with hssf a lot, please check [poi examples  page](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html)

Comment: Ok. thanks. I've already looked into API of apache POI but didn't get any solution.